# Insert and add a password in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgresql. I have a user table with the the following fields.

```
username VARCHAR(50),
password VARCHAR(50),
role_id INT(4)
```

In Mysql

```
Insert into users(username,password,role_id)values('username',md5('password'),1);
```

What is the correct way to do that/equivalent for Postgresql?

Comment: btw md5 is up to 32 chars...

Comment: Postgres doesn't have `int(4)` it's just `int` (and btw: if you were thinking `int(4)` would somehow limit the possible values up to 9999 in MySQL you were wrong). But apart from that, your `INSERT` should work just fine - what happened when you tried?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name do you have any idea why i got an error  'SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR: permission denied for relation users' after I created user table, insert some values in it.I already add a user with privileges.User as user and mypassword as password stated here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the user does not have the privileges to insert into the `users` table. Without more details how you created the table (with which user), how you run the insert and what kind of grants you granted it's impossible to tell.